# Visual Studio: Differences running project in debug and release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

My code (C#) behaves differently (in specific: a method does not work in debug-mode but in release-mode and for another method the other way around) when I#m running it in debug- and release-mode (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate). This problem has never occured to me before so I'm really confused!

Thanks in advance,
Nils

PS: I didn't post any code because I don't think it has anything to do with it - but if so I will of course.

Comment: Yes, the particular code you've got absolutely *does* matter. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, along with a rather more detailed description that "does not work".

Answer (score 2):

Can you possibly see something like this in code?

```
#if DEBUG

// Your code

#endif
```

or

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
```

If so, it will only run in debug mode.